# Is any content in Stardew Valley permanently locked to a specific time window?

Tags: stardew-valley

Just got started with Stardew Valley. One of my biggest questions is whether or not I'm playing optimally, as in, will I be missing specific events that only happen within a specific timeframe?

Note that I am not talking about season dependant events, such as the town events, or what crops grow in what seasons, etc. What I am asking is if there are any such events that are timelocked to say the first spring of the first year, and missing the time window prevents you from seeing that event again?

I've looked up this issue online, and I've found mixed responses. On some sites like GameFAQs, users claim that there are a few townsfolk that have year-specific events that can't be obtained once that year has elapsed, like relationship events for Alex, Penny, and some of the other bacherlors and bachelorettes.  On the Steam discussion boards, it seems a consensus is that there are no permanently locked out events.

So what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though they aren't time locked, there are a couple permanently missable events I was able to find on a wiki.

- [Clint's](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Clint) 6 heart event will not trigger if you've already seen [Emily's](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Emily) 8 or 10 heart event, or are married to her.
- [Penny's](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Penny) 4 heart event will not trigger if you have bought the "Community
  Upgrade" at Robin's after finishing the community center.

Also, while it isn't an "event", purchasing wood and stone at the Carpenter's Shop or coal and ore at the Blacksmith becomes more expensive after the first year has concluded.